# Pluralsight - SQL Server Replication - What course material do you recommend?

Tags: sql-server, web-services, wcf

I am in the process of trying to learn how to create a Replication Service from one SQL Server database to another - and have no idea where to start.

---

**EDIT:**

Sorry, since I'm new to this and not sure what language to use to describe my problem, I will try to make it clearer what needs to be done.  There is a large SQL Server database that contains information for company franchises.  There is another large SQL Server database that contains information for job specific data done at the franchise level.  A developer mentioned that we would need to write a service that replicates data from the first server to the next, in order for an application to access this data.  It should be a one-way pull of data.  I hope this makes it clearer.

---

I recently got a subscription to Pluralsight (lots of training videos regarding Microsoft related tools).  My question is:
**Is there a particular tutorial series (or combination of) that would point me in the direction of how to accomplish writing one of these services?**

Here is a link to their training library to give you an idea of what they offer:  http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/Courses

I searched through the videos, but found no reference to 'Replication'.  I'm assuming I would need to study some portion of the WCF courses and some portion of the SQL Server courses, but I don't know which ones will be immediately beneficial.  (Ideally I would want to study each course in great detail - but unfortunately the real world isn't allowing for that right now.)

If you know of any other resources, those would be greatly appreciated too.  Thanks!

Comment: While SQL Server has replication built into it, I'm confused by your comment regarding WCF. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I edited my question above to try and be more specific about what I'm trying to do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is truly a requirement that the data from the first server live along side the next, you could accomplish it with transactional replication, a feature that comes with SQL Server and doesn't require any external service to be written.  In your example, you'd set up your Franchises database as a publisher and then create another database on the server that has the Jobs database to act as the subscriber.  In Management studio, there's a folder called "replication" that is a sibling folder to "Databases".  Right clicking on it will get you started setting this up.  Take a look at this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) for a lot more information.

Comment: Ok, thank you - I will give this a read and take a crack at it tomorrow.